# Has "had to be" used in sarcastic sense in here?

Tags: meaning-in-context, interpretation, sarcasm

I read this in "The Last Lesson":

> I had counted on the commotion to get to my desk without being seen; but, of course, that day everything had to be as quiet as Sunday morning.

I gather that "had to be" has been used in a sarcastic tone here considering that at first the author is acknowledging that he **counted on** (implying that he believed) the commotion that was to be there but then he says that everything had to be **as quiet as** Sunday morning. Am I right? And is this much prose license really common?

Comment: Yes, you are right. "It _would_  so happen that..." is another way of expressing it.

Comment: I'm not going to read the surrounding text to get the ***full*** context, but idiomatically there are two likely implications to such use of *[of course] something **had to be** [true]*. The situation might be one where we (or someone in control) would ***naturally expect*** something to be done (and might therefore have taken steps to ensure it ***was*** done). OR it's a rueful / pessimistic allusion to "Murphy's Law" *(Anything that **can** go wrong **will** go wrong)*. As in *It has to rain the one day I forget my umbrella!*

Comment: I read this use of “had to be” as the rueful pessimism identified by FumbleFingers. I wouldn’t call it sarcasm. Another example, “We had planned an elaborate beach wedding on the Australia Day long weekend, but of course it **had to be** the wettest January since 1926!”